# Setting Up Live Wallpaper with Tasker

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, tasker, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to set up a Tasker widget to switch between a static wallpaper and a live wallpaper.

I have no problem with coming up with the action for the static wallpaper, but I am unable to change my wallpaper for the live wallpaper. Hope someone with experience could help me out here.

I am using the latest version of Tasker and the live wallpaper I wish to set up is Koi Live Wallpaper running on a rooted 4.3 stock rom Samsung S3.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a LW the only thing needed is a task with an **action of shell command** and this command in the command text box:

```
service call wallpaper 2 i32 1 s16 "com.maxelus.poweroflifelivewallpaper" s16 "com.maxelus.poweroflifelivewallpaper.WallpaperService"
```

The first argument is the **package** of the LW, then the other one is the **service**.

For example, the shell command for AudioGlow is:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: This Screenshot]

---

This command sets live wallpaper:

```
service call wallpaper 2 i32 1 s16 "[package name]" s16 "[class name]"
```

This command allows to get name of active live wallpaper:

```
service call wallpaper 4
```

And this command disables it:

```
service call wallpaper 5
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. So far, I've only manages to get the package name but not the service name. It's there a way to get it?

Comment: I would suggest you to use [Rom Toolbox Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox&hl=en) as its very popular and very useful too.
In it, Go to App Manger --> Click the App (AudioGlow) --> and choose Advance Freeze. Here you can see all the Activity name and service below it.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look into that. Thanks again, Abhioxic.